# Can Heroku load-balance WebSocket connections?

Tags: heroku, websocket, load-balancing

I use socket.io to establish a WebSocket connection between clients and a Heroku dyno (ephemeral Linux node).

Heroku load-balances HTTP connections to enable horizontal scaling (addition of dynos).

Will this load-balancing "just work" with WebSockets?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, having read [the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websockets) I believe [it can](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#websockets).

From the documentation on the Heroku router that sits in front of user dynos:

> WebSocket functionality is supported for all applications.